# How do I install LLVM 2.9 on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: installation, unix, osx-lion, llvm

I need LLVM (2.9 specifically), but I can't figure out how to follow the installation instructions. Could someone kindly provide the step by step console commands for building/installing LLVM in the proper location, and adding it to the PATH?

I am downloading the source code from [the official download page](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#2.9).

Comment: You can already download [the binaries](http://llvm.org/releases/2.9/llvm-gcc-4.2-2.9-x86_64-apple-darwin10.tar.gz), they're compiled.